# C Seconds ticking failing when need to process queries?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

We have a code a below where it keep ticking for every second it works perfectly fine. The problem starts when we have //select and insert queries need to be process for each and every second we notice there is at time gaps between 1 to 10 seconds. Thus we practically miss some processing to be done. Any idea how to overcome this? Is it that we need to create a separate thread on each second is it?Thank you.

```
void * reader_thread (void * arg) {
    while (1) {
        if (flag) {
            struct timeval tv;
            char timeBuf[10],secondBuf1[100],queryBuf1[500],queryBuf2[500];
            char buff[20] = {0};
            gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
            //fprintf (stderr, "[%d.%06d] Flag set to 1 on ", tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec);
            tv.tv_sec -= 5;
            strftime(buff, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&tv.tv_sec));
            printf("\nTime is %s", buff);

            //select and insert queries

            fprintf (stderr, " %s\n", buff);
            flag = 0;
        }
        usleep  (100); // will skew the processing but not signal delivery
    }
    return NULL;
}

void callback (int sig) {
    flag = 1; // this is the only thing the callback does
}

int main () {
    timer_t tid = 0;
    pthread_t thread;
    struct itimerspec it;
    char *localServer = "localhost", *remoteServer = "localhost";
                       char *localUser = "user1", *remoteUser = "user2";
                       char *localPassword = "****", *remotePassword = "*****";
                       char *localDatabase = "db1", *remoteDatabase = "db1";
                       localConn = mysql_init(NULL), remoteConn = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (!mysql_real_connect(localConn, localServer,
                         localUser, localPassword, localDatabase, 0, NULL, 0)) {
                      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(localConn));
                      exit(1);
                   }   



    pthread_create (&thread, NULL, reader_thread, NULL);

    signal (SIGALRM, callback);

    it.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    it.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    it.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    it.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    timer_create (CLOCK_REALTIME, NULL, &tid);
    timer_settime (tid, 0, &it, NULL);

    while (1) sleep (100);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit codes.

```
sigset_t sigset;
        sigfillset(&sigset);

        if (pthread_sigmask(
            SIG_BLOCK,
            &sigset,
            NULL))
        {
          perror("pthread_sigmask");
        }

    pthread_create (&thread, NULL, reader_thread, NULL);

    //sigset_t sigset;
    //sigemptyset(&sigset);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGALRM);

        if (pthread_sigmask(
            SIG_UNBLOCK,
            &sigset,
            NULL))
        {
          perror("pthread_sigmask");
        }
```

Comment: The way you use signals is not optimal: 1 Verbatim from `man signal`: `The effects of signal() in a multithreaded process are unspecified.` 2 `sleep()` and `usleep()` will be interupted if the thread which called them receives a signal. 3 It is not specified which thread will receive `SIGALRM`.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to set up this a bit differently:

1 **Before spawning any thread** use `pthread_sigmask()` to make the app ignore all signals. This behaviour will then be inheritied by any thread created afterwards and will make them not eat away any signals, as only the main thread is to handle them (see step 2 below).

2 **After having created all threads** use `pthread_sigmask()`again to make the main thread receive `SIGALRM` and use `sigaction()` (instead of `signal()`; also see my comment on the OP) to set up the signal handler for `SIGALRM`.

3 Declare a **flag for each thread**. Currently a thread resetting the flag might do this before another thread had started.

---

If the main thread does not have to do anthing alse (or you do not mind spawning another thread): Alternativly to installing a signal handler using `sigaction()` (as described in step 2 above) you could use something like `do { int sig = sigwaitinfo(...); ... } while (1);` to pull the signals received from the the queue and set the flags used to trigger the start of the queries.

---

**Update**:

Example on how to use `pthread_sigmask()` to block **all** signals for the calling thread:

```
sigset_t sigset;
sigfillset(&sigset);

if (pthread_sigmask(
    SIG_BLOCK,
    &sigset,
    NULL))
{
  perror("pthread_sigmask");
}
```

Example on how to use `pthread_sigmask()` to unblock `SIGALRM` for the calling thread:

```
sigset_t sigset;
sigemptyset(&sigset);
sigaddset(&sigset, SIGALRM);

if (pthread_sigmask(
    SIG_UNBLOCK,
    &sigset,
    NULL))
{
  perror("pthread_sigmask");
}
```

For more details on `pthread_sigmask()`  please see `man pthread_sigmask()`.

Comment: which part of the main should I add now the pthread_sigmask() or should I replace the signal with this is it? So what should be content for the sigaction then it will be the calling of the thread right?

Comment: @user837306: for your first question please see my updated 2 in my answer. Your second question I do not really understand. For details on how to use `sigaction()` please see `man sigaction`.

Comment: I think this is how it suppose to be right  pthread_sigmask();
pthread_create (&thread, NULL, reader_thread, NULL); //signal (SIGALRM, callback);pthread_sigmask(); . My problem now for the sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL) I do not know what should I specify for the &act in my case here?

Comment: Assuming you pass the correct parameters to the call to `pthread_sigmask()`: yes.

Comment: I am not too sure will it be like this pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, reader_thread, NULL);? Sorry kind of very new to all this signalling stuff.

Comment: where to put this new code not in the main right in the thread function right?

Comment: Blocking/unblocking signals using `pthread_sigmask()` shall be done before/after creating threads, just as I wrote under 1 and 2 in my answer. @user837306

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13907/discussion-between-user837306-and-alk)

Comment: I have put in my original question the section on edit code. I can compile and it run and just print "Alarm Clock" ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - may/may not be the one you are looking for - you could do something like keep adding the select and insert queries to a queue in reader_thread and have a separate thread for a function which takes the queries from the queue and actually executes them.

Comment: I have in total 4 selects and 4 inserts to be done. How to handle those? Any sample codes to guide me? Thank you.

Comment: U didnt mention about this in the original question so I thought of the general scenario and gave the answer , if there are only 8 operations , a thread for each would probably not hurt much I guess.

Comment: I have tried individual thread just for one whole bunch of  sql queries still same too.